# Regex string definition issue

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make regex which will match all `console.log("anything");` in the file. I wrote next pattern string:

```
@"(console\.log\(\"(.*)\"\)\;)"
```

The compiler doesn't compile code and says:

> Method, Delegate or event is expected.

The problem is with stripslashing - `"` characters. But I don't know how to fix it, any ideas?

I use this pattern in method:

```
  js.RegexReplace(@"(console\.log\(\"(.*)\"\)\;)", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

`js` is a string variable.

`RegexReplace` signature:

```
string RegexReplace(this string input, string pattern, string replacement, RegexOptions options)
```

Comment: Show the relevant method, delegate or event code as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double double quotation marks:

`@"(console\.log\(""(.*)""\);)"`

**EDIT:**
You do not have to escape `""`s when using verbatim strings.
So, the C# code will look like:

```
var pattern = @"(console\.log\(""(.*)""\);)";
```

Comment: Correct, but you might as well get rid of the backslash while you're at it.  The quotation mark has no special meaning in a regex, so you don't need to escape it with a backslash (`\""`).  Just use `""` to escape it for the verbatim string literal and you're done.  You don't need to escape the semicolon, either.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thank you, I updated my answer. I focused on the verbatim string problem, and forgot to check the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the verbatim and the escape character. That is not working as you expect, since you can't use `\` to escape `"`, but need to use `"`.

Use this string with the verbatim:

```
@"(console\.log\(""(.*)""\)\;)"
```

Use this string, without the verbatim:

```
"(console\\.log\\(\"(.*)\"\\)\\;)"
```

Comment: But how to do it with verbatim? Just interesting.

Comment: You can't, since you can't use `\` to escape `"`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman:  Can't use a verbatim string?  Of course you can!  You just escape the quote with another quote instead of with a backslash.